# I am getting access denied in Ubuntu terminal after sudo chmod 754 .. from /home. Do I have a brick now?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, root

In effect, I changed the permissions of / to 754

The machine is 14.04

I cannot type any shell command as it says permission denied.
-bash: /bin/ls: Permission denied

I can't even use sudo to change the permissions on /
-bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied

Fortunately the machine is still running and I have a PUTTY terminal still open.

Do I have a quasi brick?

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of what you try, you're going to have to create a bootable Ubuntu USB. Once you have the bootable USB, boot from it, and then you can either try to painstakingly change all of the permissions (do not recommend), or backup all of your data and reinstall the system.

Remember that you will have to locate your hard disk and mount it before doing anything. You can use `fdisk -l` for this or `lsblk`

Comment: are all my permissions changed, or just /

Comment: Ah that is a good point! I was under the assumption that you did ``chmod -R `` on / which would be recursive and would change the permissions of everything in the system. You only did it on / so you were able to fix it. I should have asked that question or pointed that out.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue.

I rebooted linux into recovery mode.
I selected extra options.
I dropped into superuser mode
i changed the permission of / back to 755

rebooted - works

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but FYI: when it says `-bash: /bin/ls: Permission denied` that means `/bin/ls` is the (program) file on which permission was denied -- which could be at any level of its path, and you have identified the problem was actually on `/` (only). `-bash:` means the error message is *from* your login (top-level) `bash` process; it does not mean any file `-bash` or `/-bash` exists anywhere or has any problem that should be fixed.

Also `/` is *not* the same as `/home`. At all.

And although Ubuntu 14.04 was LTS, it is now past its sell-by date and no longer supported. Consider if that's what you want.